# Why is returned li tag not rendering? ESlint is expecting a return value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While testing, I have come across this error. I read the React docs and proceeded to use .map, the =>, and

tag according to their documentation but nothing has rendered to the screen. If I can be pointed in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      ideas: [
        {
          title: "Titanic",
          director: [
            {
              James: "Cameron"
            }
          ],
          year: 1998
        },
        {
          title: "Star Wars",
          director: [
            {
              George: "Lucas"
            }
          ],
          year: 1974
        },
        {
          title: "Alien",
          director: [
            {
              Ridley: "Scott"
            }
          ],
          year: 1985
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { ideas } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1> hi </h1>
        {ideas.map((item, index) => {
          <li key={index}>{item.title}</li>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: It's because you're not returning anything. Either use parenthesis or add explicit return between curly braces. For syntax refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Syntax)

Comment: Your <li> elements are not wrapped by a <ul> or <ol> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback passed to `.map()` has to return the `<li>`:

```
  <div>
    <h1> hi </h1>
    {ideas.map((item, index) => {
      return (<li key={index}>{item.title}</li>);
//    ^^^^^^
    })}
  </div>
```

Or implicit return :

```
  <div>
    <h1> hi </h1>
    {ideas.map((item, index) => (<li key={index}>{item.title}</li>))}
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I did not realize you have to wrap the li in parenthesis for the implicit return